# Populate a SQL column based on another column

Tags: sql

I have a table like what is below, and I need to update the `Attachment` column to = 1 if the `TypeID = 1` and there is also a matching invoice number with `TypeID = 3`. I know there is a simple answer but I'm honestly just stuck on how to start. Eventually this will be included in a much larger ETL so I prefer to avoid having to use a temp table if possible.

Current state:

| TypeID | InvoiceNumber | Attachment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | I78671666 | NULL |
| 1 | I78671666 | NULL |
| 3 | I78671759 | NULL |
| 1 | I78671759 | NULL |
| 1 | I78671762 | NULL |
| 1 | I78671903 | NULL |
| 3 | I78672198 | NULL |
| 1 | I78672198 | NULL |

Desired outcome:

| TypeID | InvoiceNumber | Attachment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | I78671666 | NULL |
| 1 | I78671666 | 1 |
| 3 | I78671759 | NULL |
| 1 | I78671759 | 1 |
| 1 | I78671762 | NULL |
| 1 | I78671903 | NULL |
| 3 | I78672198 | NULL |
| 1 | I78672198 | 1 |

Comment: You need to implement a trigger. A calculated column would not get you there since the input to your calculation is partially dependent on the existence of another row.

Comment: UPDATE is DBMS specific. What you use?

Comment: @valnik using SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Your natural language rules reworded directly into SQL:

```sql
update the_table t1 
set attachment = 1 
where typeid = 1 and exists (
  select 1 from the_table t2 
  where t2.invoicenumber = t1.invoicenumber and t2.typeid = 3
);
```

DB Fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c1Yw5FJeGGEMbSKPKuFD4P/0)

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
update test
  set  Attachment=1
from (select InvoiceNumber from test where TypeId=3) I3
where test.TypeId=1 and I3.invoiceNumber=test.InvoiceNumber
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8uhPwlO7)